# Avoid repeated data in $lookup Pipeline stage

Tags: mongodb

I am executing this query to get system log & email log data from two different collections with the following query. The two collections have different structure.

```
db.getCollection('system_logs').aggregate([
{$match: {entity_id: 10}},
{"$lookup": {
    "from":         "mail_success_log",
    "localField":   "entity_id",
    "foreignField": "contact_id",
    "as":           "email_logs",
}}
])
```

Getting the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "entity_id": 10,
    "activity" : "yahoo - new contact added",
    "created_on" : NumberLong(1614855389),
    "email_logs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            "created_on" : NumberLong(1614860067),
            "log" : {
                "subject" : "A",
                "email_id" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            "receiver_email" : "abc@example.com",
            "sender_email" : "xyz@example.com",
            "contact_id": 10
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            "created_on" : NumberLong(1614860067),
            "log" : {
                "subject" : "A",
                "email_id" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            "receiver_email" : "abc@example.com",
            "sender_email" : "xyz@example.com",
            "contact_id": 10
        },
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "entity_id": 10,
    "activity" : "yahoo - contact updated",
    "created_on" : NumberLong(1614855380),
    "email_logs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            "created_on" : NumberLong(1614860067),
            "log" : {
                "subject" : "A",
                "email_id" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            "receiver_email" : "abc@example.com",
            "sender_email" : "xyz@example.com",
            "contact_id": 10
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            "created_on" : NumberLong(1614860067),
            "log" : {
                "subject" : "A",
                "email_id" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            "receiver_email" : "abc@example.com",
            "sender_email" : "xyz@example.com",
            "contact_id": 10
        },
    ]
}
```

In the above data, I am getting repeated email logs with each system log object. Is there a way to get this repeated data only once, not with every system log object ?

**Note:**  Is this a good practice to approach this ? or I should try some other query ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $project with the lookup.

```
{ $project: { "<field1>": 0, "<field2>": 0, ... } } // Return all but the specified fields
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: thanks for the answer but I need this data only once not with every system log object. Is that possible ?